# How to run bash script with at command on freebsd

Tags: shell-script, freebsd, at

I have a bash script that it should start at a specific time. I used from at command. When I run it with at, the job create and after the time the job start but it doesn't do it's work. When I run the script without at it works well. I think the problem is bash because it runs sh scripts.

This a part of my script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

IFS=' ' read -r -a array <<< "$LIST"
for element in "${array[@]}"
  do
    touch /tmp/$element.call
    cat >> /tmp/$element.call <<-EOF
    Channel: SIP/${element}
    Application: Playback
    Data:${FILE}
    Callerid: ${CALLERID}
    EOF
    mv /tmp/$element.call  /var/spool/asterisk/outgoing/
done
```

I run the at command like below:

```
export FILE=hello-world.gsm LIST=4001 5001 6001  CALLERID=123; sudo -E at -t 20210140636.00 -f  /usr/local/bin/asterisk_wakeup_call.sh
```

would you please help me to find the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Could you add a line with `echo test $FILE $LIST $CALLERID > /home/fm/at-test` in the beginning. I assume that the variables are not exported as expected.

Comment: @Fiximan I test it. the file content is correct

Comment: You could replace the shebang with `#!/usr/local/bin/bash -x` and check the logs for the output. Anything obvious there?

Comment: @Fiximan  when I set -x option, with `at` it doesn't show logs. I run script without `at ` it worked.
`FILE=hello-world.gsm LIST=4001 5001 6001  CALLERID=123  /usr/local/bin/asterisk_wakeup_call.sh`

Comment: I suspect that `at` is being run from the original user's queue, but the sudo privilege has expired, or cannot be reinstated by the daemon that runs the job.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant  I tested it with root user. The owner of `/var/at/` is `daemon` user. where should be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The commands read from standard input, or from the file given to the `-f` option, are executed by `sh` on FreeBSD, according to the [`at(1)` manual](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=at&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+12.2-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html).  This means that the `#!`-line of your script is ignored.

To have your script execute properly, schedule the execution of the script instead of the commands in the script file.

You do this, for example, like so:

```bsh
echo /usr/local/bin/asterisk_wakeup_call.sh | at -t 20210140636.00
```

Your complete command (assuming that `LIST` should be a string with space-separated numbers):

```bsh
sudo env \
    FILE=hello-world.gsm \
    LIST='4001 5001 6001' \
    CALLERID=123 \
    sh -c 'echo /usr/local/bin/asterisk_wakeup_call.sh | at -t 20210140636.00'
```

or,

```bsh
echo /usr/local/bin/asterisk_wakeup_call.sh |
sudo env \
    FILE=hello-world.gsm \
    LIST='4001 5001 6001' \
    CALLERID=123 \
    at -t 20210140636.00
```

This also uses `env` to pass the environment variables to the shell that we start, which is safer than using `sudo -E`.  If there are other environment variables that needs to be passed as-is, then you might obviously do this in whatever way you want.

Also note that your time specification, `20210140636.00`, is wrong.  It lacks one digit somewhere (probably in the specification of the day): `2021 01 40 636 .00`

Comment: Thank for your reply. I tested it but it doesn't do anything. Another guess I made was that it did not have permission. I set the user daemon in sudoers but no succeed

Comment: @F.M Did you correct the time specification that I pointed out was wrong? Also, you could try running it as `at now + 1 minutes` as a test.  Does the root user get any email from the cron daemon about errors?  I don't understand what you mean about setting the `daemon` user in `sudoers`.  Care to explain?